# Ошибка Unexpected end of input

Tags: php, javascript, dle

Всем привет. У меня ошибка.

Вот js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.del_urls', function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var message = $(this).attr("title");
            var dlink = $(this).attr("href");
            var answer = confirm(message);
            if (answer) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: dlink,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if (msg = "ok") {
                            parent.remove();
                            console.log("ok");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (jQuery().uploadify) {
            $('#uploadify').uploadify({
                'debug': false,
                'buttonText': 'Загрузка файлов',
                'buttonCursor': 'pointer',
                'uploader': 'engine/uploadify/upload-uploadify.php',
                'swf': 'engine/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true,
                'height': '30',
                'width': '100%',
                'requeueErrors': false,
                'fileSizeLimit': '512000', // expects input in kb
                'cancelImage': 'engine/uploadify/bcancel.png',
                'checkExisting': 'engine/uploadify/uploadify-check-exists.php',
                'postData': {
                    'news_id': '{$row['
                    id ']}'
                },
                onUploadProgress: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                onUploadSuccess: function(file, data, response) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if (data.msg = "ok") {
                        $('#load_urls').prepend(data.url);
                    }
                },
                onSelectError: function(file, errorCode, errorMsg) {
                    //alert(file + ' Error ' + errorCode +':'+errorMsg);
                },
                onUploadError: function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                    alert(errorMsg);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

А вот php:

```
define( 'DATALIFEENGINE', true );
define( 'ROOT_DIR', substr( dirname(  __FILE__ ), 0, -17 ) );
define( 'ENGINE_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '/engine' );
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!=="site.com") die();

require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/data/config.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/mysql.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/data/dbconfig.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/inc/include/functions.inc.php';

$poddomen=parse_url($config['poddomen_url']);
define( 'PREFIX_DIR', date("m-Y")."/" );
define( 'UPLOAD_DIR', substr( dirname(  __FILE__ ), 0, -17-strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ).$poddomen['host']."/files/" );

$_TIME = time ();

if (isset($_REQUEST['del'])) {
    $id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);
    $row = $db->super_query( "SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files WHERE news_id = '{$id}'" );
    if($row) {
        $urls=$row['files'];
        $urls=str_replace($_REQUEST['f']."||", "", $urls);
        if (strlen($urls)>8) {
            $row2=$db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files SET files='{$urls}'  WHERE news_id='{$id}'" );
            if ($row2) {
                @unlink(UPLOAD_DIR.$_REQUEST['f']);
                echo "ok";
            }
        } else {
            $db->query( "DELETE FROM " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files WHERE news_id='{$id}'" );
            @unlink(UPLOAD_DIR.$_REQUEST['f']);
        }

    }
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

if( intval( $_REQUEST['news_id'] ) ) $news_id = intval( $_REQUEST['news_id'] ); else $news_id = 0;

        if( !is_dir( UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR ) ) {          
            @mkdir( UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR, 0777 );
            @chmod( UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR, 0777 );
        }
        if( !is_dir( UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR ) ) {          
            die("Ne vozmozhno sozdat papku".UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR);
        }
        if (!is_writable(UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR)) {
            die("Papka ".UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR." no dostupna dlya zapisi");
        }

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $new_name = time()."_".$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile = rtrim(UPLOAD_DIR . PREFIX_DIR,'/') . '/' .$new_name;

    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','zip','mp4','rar'); 
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    $row = $db->super_query( "SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files WHERE news_id = '{$news_id}'" );
    if($row) {
        $files=PREFIX_DIR.$new_name."||".$row['files'];
        $db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files SET news_id='{$news_id}', files='{$files}'  WHERE news_id='{$news_id}'" );
    } else {
        $db->query( "INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files (news_id, files) values ('{$news_id}', '".PREFIX_DIR.$new_name."||')" );
    }
    $url=$config['poddomen_url'] . 'files/' . PREFIX_DIR.$new_name;
    $insert="<div><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$url."\"><a class=\"del_urls\" title=\"Удалить файл {$new_name}?\" href=\"engine/ajax/uploads.php?id={$news_id}&f=".PREFIX_DIR.$new_name."&del\">del</a></div>";

        echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"ok", "url"=>"{$insert}"));

    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}

// Это еще код!
        $pod_files = $db->super_query( "SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_poddomen_files WHERE news_id = '{$id}'" );
    if ($pod_files) {
        $pod_urls = rtrim($pod_files['files'], "||");
        $pod_urls = explode("||", $pod_urls);
        $echo_pod_urls = "";
        foreach ($pod_urls as $pod_url) {
            $f_name = end(explode("/", $pod_url));
            $echo_pod_urls .= <<<HTML
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value="{$config['poddomen_url']}files/{$pod_url}" />
                    <a class="del_urls" title="Удалить файл {$f_name}?" href="engine/uploadify/upload-uploadify.php?id={$id}&f={$pod_url}&del">del</a>
                </div>
HTML;
        }
    }
    else $echo_pod_urls = "";
```

Comment: @reeeeeeeee, очень похоже на забытую где-то скобку, откройте любой ide с подсветской кода, она подскажет.

Comment: Сижу через sublime, все нормально, ошибок нет.  
Просто сижу сейчас на php 5.5, на php 5.3 все нормально. Как сделать на php 5.5?

Comment: @reeeeeeeee, для начала хотя бы привести весь текст ошибки, а в идеале еще и выделить то место, которое к ней приводит.

Comment: Вот весь текст ошибки:

>Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 1):

[@reeeeeeeee](/users/24241/reeeeeeeee), у вас в

```
onUploadSuccess: function(file, data, response) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    if (data.msg = "ok") {
        $('#load_urls').prepend(data.url);
    }
},
```

приходит невалидный json, вероятнее всего потому что success считается по коду 200, а сервак возвращает просто текст через die. Установите нужный статус ответа, и будете видеть, что не так сервер сделал.

Comment: А как это сделать, я просто null?
_____
Меня еще вот это строка беспокоит - `end(explode("/", $pod_url));`.

Comment: Никого не смущает, что в if присваивание, а не сравнение? if(data.msg === "ok") будет так-то правильнее)